# Simple text input field accepting line breaks

Tags: user-interface, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a simple way to get this to work?

```
text = "";
DialogInput[{TextCell["Try to type a text with linebreaks :-)"],
  InputField[Dynamic[text], String], 
  Button["Ok", DialogReturn[text]]}]
```

The problem is that InputField terminates after typing `Return`. I just want a simple text input field.

Comment: Chris Degnen published his solution to this problem here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a2b1cfa8efa6df9  (see his last post there)

Comment: @Leonid: You should put that into an answer (or invite Chris to).

Comment: @Simon Ok, thanks for the suggestion, that makes sense. I posted it, although it would be better if Chris did it himself - he put a lot of effort into getting it to work, and this is a non-trivial problem. I can speak only for myself, but I gave up at some point, until I saw his post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up Leonid. Here is the code:

```
text = "";
DialogInput[{TextCell["Try to type a text with linebreaks :-)"], 
  InputField[Dynamic[text], String, FieldSize -> {30, 6}], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn[text]]}, 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
    FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n"]]}]
```

The FrontEndExecute statement is a little simpler in this version.

Incidentally, to clear the default Return key action of NotebookEventActions you can use `NotebookEventActions->{}`. This can be useful to stop dialogs disappearing during input.

Comment: Great! I deleted my post. I hope those who voted for it will spend some extra votes for your answer, since this is where those votes belong.